# Beamer: Column Env

Tags: beamer, errors, columns

I could not find why column environment is not working. Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Conduction
    \item Convection
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> Forced
        \item<2-> Natural
    \end{itemize}
    \item Radiation
    \end{itemize}
\column 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Rayleigh No.
    \item Grashof No.
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's rather `\begin{column}{<width>}...\end{column}` inside the columns environment no?

Comment: In addition, to using `\begin{column}{<width>}...\end{column}`, as percusse says, you can also specify the column width using `\column[⟨placement⟩]{⟨column width⟩}`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\column{0.5\textwidth}`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.5\textwidth} 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Conduction
        \item Convection
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<2-> Forced
            \item<2-> Natural
        \end{itemize}
        \item Radiation
    \end{itemize}
    \column{0.5\textwidth} 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Rayleigh No.
        \item Grashof No.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```